Are alicorns immortal?
In My Little Pony, are Alicorns immortal? It feels like they have been around since forever.

Welcome user. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when. Have the writers ever killed a character? (We deal with cannon rather than fan-fiction versions)

Have you looked at the Alicorns page on the MLP fandom site?  While the rulers are described (in the show) as immortal, one of the creators says that Twilight Sparkle (at least) is not.

@DavidW oh this is really helpful. Thank you so much! I had not seen this.
